# Delphi XE2 and Char/Byte type

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

i have this problem, look this code of example:

```
src := '';
for iindex := 0 to 255 do
  begin
    src := src + char(byte(iindex));
    writeln (iindex:5, byte(src[iindex]):5);
  end;
```

where src is a string type and iindex is a integer type and as output i should to have something as:

```
iIndex   byte(src[iIndex])
 0         0
 1         1
 2         2
 3         3
 ..................
 254       254
 255       255
```

and so was too in all lasts version of delphi until to delphi xe; now with delphi xe2, i have this output:

```
iIndex   byte(src[iIndex])
 0         0
 1         0
 2         1
 3         2
 ..................
 254       253
 255       254
```

Now i ask, need use different type of string? I have found a workaround for solve it of course, updating  byte(src[iindex]) to byte(src[succ(iindex)]) but so when iIndex = 255, i have byte(src[256]) that raise a exception and so need change byte in word.
Of course, i don't think that it is the best solution, so i ask you if there is a better solution to it.
Thanks very much.

Comment: How is src declared? Anyway, surely you meant to write `ord(src[iIndex])` rather than `byte(...)`?

Comment: src is declared as:   var src: string;    if i use ord at place of byte, it is awfull result, i have   0, 255, 1, etc  and not 0, 1, 2 with index: 0, 1, 2 respectly.

Comment: @david:  using ord(src[iIndex]) i have: 0 for iIndex = 0; 255 for iIndex = 1; 0 for iIndex 2; etc etc.. for iIndex = 255 i have 253. awfull :( some idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are accessing the string out-of-bounds. String access is 1-based in Delphi. You should be getting a range check error. Also, I think you should prefer using `chr()` and `ord()` instead of the casts.

```
src := '';
for iindex := 0 to 255 do
begin
  src := src + chr(iindex);
  writeln (iindex:5, ord(src[iindex+1]):5);
end;
```

I don't see that the code could work in earlier versions of Delphi. Indeed Delphi 2010 behaves exactly as you describe XE2 behaving once range checking is disabled. This is yet another example of why range checking is so valuable.

Comment: Thanks very much. So work. Just until delphi xe i have every used char/byte conversion to place of chr/ord and was every ok. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Marcello The real issue is the indexing and note that there appears to be nothing different in XE2's handling of this code.

Comment: Yes, it true. I tell about original code that i have posted to begin. Under delphi xe infact, it so as is, not gived issue to me. In this sense i tell, but now i have understood better where i mistake :)

Comment: If there was no "issue", that means you were lucky. src[0] was always invalid, but happened to return the value you expected. I just wonder how you ever got a `1` out of the first index of the string.